# Add a buttons to rows of DataGrid and Event_Click to each using Caliburn micro in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I am trying to add a button "View" to to a series of rows (last cell of the row) of factures in DataGrid (using c#, WPF, Caliburn micro mvvm). Each button should have a handler that views the details of that facture in another form.

Questions:

1. How can I add this button at row ends?
2. How can I add the event handler?

I will only view the function that I am using to add the word "View" at the last column of each row.

I tried adding a button using: `Button btn = new Button();` And set its required parameters. But that didn't work.

***I will share the whole xaml and ViewModel files:***

```
<UserControl x:Class="Factures.Views.FactureView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Factures.Views"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             cal:Bind.Model="Shell"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
    <Grid IsEnabled="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" 
                  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                  x:Name="Factures"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Factures}"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  MinWidth="100" MinHeight="50" 
                  FontFamily="Times New Roman"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="BtnView"
                                    cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[BtnView($dataContext)]"
                                    Content="View Facture">

                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Factures.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Factures.ViewModels
{
    public class FactureViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        public BindableCollection<FactureModel> Factures { get; set; }

        public FactureViewModel()
        {
            FactureModel facture = new FactureModel();
            DataTable allFactures = facture.All();

            //Fill Bindable collection
            this.FillAllFactures(allFactures);
        }

        public void BtnView(object row)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }   

        private void FillAllFactures(DataTable factures)
        {
            List<FactureModel> output = new List<FactureModel>();
            foreach(DataRow row in factures.Rows)
            {
                FactureModel fm = new FactureModel
                {
                    Id = System.Convert.ToInt32(row[0].ToString()),
                    Name = row[1].ToString(),
                };

                output.Add(fm);
            }
            this.Factures = new BindableCollection<FactureModel>(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataGridTemplateColumn and Caliburn Micro's Action message syntax to use a Button for each row in your datagrid.

For first part of your question, you can add a button to each row of your Datagrid using DataGridTemplateColumn.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="View" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[ViewUser($dataContext)]"></Button>
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Complete definition of DataGrid in your XAML would look like.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" Header="UserName"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="View" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[ViewUser($dataContext)]"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The `cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[ViewUser($dataContext)]"` would use the Caliburn.Micro Action syntax to enable you to invoke a method on Click event of each button. The $dataContext parameter allows you to pass the corresponding Selected Data Item as parameter to the Method.

Your ViewModel method would look like

```
    public void ViewUser(object user)
    {
    // Do work
    }
```

You can read more on Caliburn.Micro Actions [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions).

Comment: I did that, the button seems to be disabled. Any Idea??

Comment: @MoonMoon Do you have a guard method declared ? In above case, "CanViewUser" ? Caliburn Micro uses "Can" prefix to the method name for Guard methods

Comment: No I don't have guard method.

Comment: Also there are so many issues in using `cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[ViewUser($dataContext)]"`

Comment: Like having to use `xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             cal:Bind.Model="Shell"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
` In the xaml file under UserControl

Comment: Also I have to add `using System.ComponentModel.Composition;` in the ViewModel File which has to be installed in the References. As In (in Solution right click -> add reference -> search for System.ComponentModel.Composition -> install

Comment: Also I have: to do this ```[Export("Shell", typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    //same as before
}```

Comment: And till now I can't fix the error IShell doesn't exist.

Comment: I was able to fix `Export` by `using System.ComponentModel.Composition;` after installing it in references though

Comment: Tons of issues just to fix something as easy as adding a button at the end of each row of a DataGrid :@. Sorry its been just a week using WPF and Caliburn micro for me

Comment: If I remove `[Export("Shell", typeof(IShell))]` line I can avoid the IShell doesn't exist error. But THE BUTTON IS DISABLED

Comment: Please try to view my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579229/datagrid-is-always-disabled It shows in details the problem about button being disabled

Comment: I deleted that disabled DataGrid question because I was able to fix it in a very easy fix, not worth to be added on this site. It was a big mistake on my part for not noticing something `<Grid IsEnabled="True">` that the grid's IsEnabled was set to false.

Comment: Now the button is enabled but I cant execute the BtnView() method for buttons

Comment: I shared the whole XAML and ViewModel Files. Now the application goes into Break Point

Comment: FIXED HORRAYYYYYYY

Comment: @MoonMoon Glad to know that you were able to fix it. What was the issue ?

Comment: I had to add `xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"` in the UserControl and that is all your answer had only that missing. Thanks for your help.